# Mongoose subdocument and attribute with the name of "type"

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Using Mongoose to connect to database:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var poi_schema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  geo: { // GeoJSON
    type: String,
    coordinates: [Number, Number]
  }
});

var Poi = mongoose.model('Poi', poi_schema);


var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
    var poi = new Poi();
    poi.name = 'hello';
    poi.geo.type = 'Point';
    poi.geo.coordinates = [34, 23];
    poi.save(function(err, poi) {
      if (err) console.error('save error', err);
      else console.log(poi._id, poi.name, 'saved');
    });
});
```

This will fail with error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined`.

As soon as I change the word "type" to something else, it does work.
Why? And I'm actually trying to store GeoJSON using 2dsphere indexing, and I think that requires the field name to be called "type". And with Mongoose it doesn't work?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it in this way:

```
  geo: { // GeoJSON
    type: {type: String},
    coordinates: [Number, Number]
  }
```

For using 2dsphere indexing, you don't need type: 'Point' property unless you want to store more than just Point.

Comment: As you put `type: String`,  mongoose think that geo has String type.

Comment: Oh!! I see. I see why this could have been now.